# Why images makes a gap around?

Tags: html, css, image

I'd like to ask, why there is a gap around the images. Is there something about this behaviour in the specification?

Simple code where you can see the gap between images:

```
<style>img {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;}</style>    

<img><br>
<img><br>
<img>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfptspj0/

I know that there is more posibilities how to remove this gap:

1. display: block;
2. float
3. vertical-align

But I want to know why there is the gap, not how to remove that.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: The fiddle shows nothing

Comment: @Huangism: really? Read the question once again :-)

Comment: The code and the fiddle have invalid `img` tags that do not refer to any image or to any textual replacement for an image, so it is meaningless to refer to rendering of images in that context.

Comment: @panther I read the question correctly and wanted to see the gap and your fiddle does not show the gaps since it shows nothing

Comment: @Huangism: Ah sorry, probably it works in chrome and maybe elsewhere not. Answer is below, piers saw the fiddle correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If an image is displayed inline, it leaves a slight space below it.
>   This is because the image is placed on the baseline of the text, and
>   below the baseline there should be some more space for the descender
>   characters like g, j or q.

Source: http://www.schoonzie.com/rogue-padding-below-images